# Javascript background slideshow (default image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

This is simple javascript slideshow.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var bgimages=new Array()
bgimages[0]="im1.jpg"
bgimages[1]="im2.jpg"
bgimages[2]="im3.jpg"

//preload images
var pathToImg=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgimages.length;i++){
pathToImg[i]=new Image()
pathToImg[i].src=bgimages[i]
}
var inc=-1

function bgSlide(){
if (inc<bgimages.length-1)
inc++
else
inc=0
document.body.background=pathToImg[inc].src
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
window.onload=new Function('setInterval("bgSlide()",8000)')

</script>
```

Problem is that slideshow start after 8s . So when page load it is white page for 8s. When i set default image for body via css slideshow does not work. How i can fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
window.onload=new Function('bgSlide(); setInterval("bgSlide()",8000)')
```

Call the function that triggers the slide, then set the interval.  You get the result now and then every 8 seconds afterwards.

Comment: That may be difficult to avoid, and may vary dramatically with your user's connection speed.  Your best bet there may be to insert a very small image file to use as a "loading" placeholder until the slideshow starts.

Comment: Thanks, and question: why funny? this is best way for slide bg. I tried a few other jquery ways and the page scroll slow.

Comment: I take that back - I saw the capital 'F' in Function and my brain got suspicious, but you're just using a syntax I don't think I've seen before.  I looked it up and it's perfectly good code.  Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: Why construct a function out of text this way instead of just defining the function dynamically (`window.onload = function() { bgSlide(); setInterval(bgSlide, 8000); };`)?

Comment: I just made the minimal change to Fakt7's code to answer the question.  Your comment might be better directed at the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

You can just call bgSlide() first and then with interval

Answer (score -1):

`setTimeout` would work in this case.

```
function bgSlide() {
    // your code
    setTimeout(bgSlide, 8000);
}
window.onload = bgSlide();
```